# STM CubeIDE 1.9.0 has linker issues?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

Prolog: I am using STM32 CubeIDE to develop embedded application for STM32 Microcontrollers, like the F1 Series, the F4 Series, the G0 series and some others with C.

What happened:
Today morning the automatic update feature suggested me to update to STM CubeID Version 1.9.0 and i accepted. After the updater had finished, I opened my current project and changed one variable in a typedef struct and hit the "build" button. All of a sudden the linker reported lots of "multiple definition" and "first defined here" errors. This project was compiling perfectly without any issues yesterday with CubeIDE Version 1.8

After searching an hour or two, where I could have missed a semicolon or something in that direction, which could mess up the whole code, I came to the conclusion, that the upgrade from CubeIDE 1.8.0 to 1.9.0 might be the root cause for this errors.

So I decided to uninstall CubeIDE 1.9.0 and reinstall Version 1.8.0, rolled back the project to the last working version from yesterday evening (compiled with 1.8.0), made the same changes, and Voila! - anything worked well again.

For me it looks like STM messed something up with the linker. Can anyone confirm this behavior, or was only me affected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to compiler update. From the release notes of STM32CubeIDE:

> GCC 10 support by default

From [GCC 10 release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html):

> GCC now defaults to -fno-common. As a result, global variable accesses
> are more efficient on various targets. In C, global variables with
> multiple tentative definitions now result in linker errors. With
> -fcommon such definitions are silently merged during linking.

[This page](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/porting_to.html) has futher explanation and a workaround:

> A common mistake in C is omitting extern when declaring a global
> variable in a header file. If the header is included by several files
> it results in multiple definitions of the same variable. In previous
> GCC versions this error is ignored. GCC 10 defaults to -fno-common,
> which means a linker error will now be reported. To fix this, use
> extern in header files when declaring global variables, and ensure
> each global is defined in exactly one C file. If tentative definitions
> of particular variables need to be placed in a common block,
> `__attribute__((__common__))` can be used to force that behavior even in code compiled without -fcommon. As a workaround, legacy C code where
> all tentative definitions should be placed into a common block can be
> compiled with -fcommon.

Comment: for anyone who needs some more extra information, about using the "extern" keyword: the anwser to your questions can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files/1433387?r=SearchResults#1433387 - this is IMHO the best readable / understandable explanation or "quick start guide" for this topic

Answer (score 2):

In Project > Properties > C/C++ build > Settings > gcc compiler > miscellaneous > Other flags, try adding `-fcommon` as shown below to avoid the 1k+ linker error issue with STM CubeIDE 1.9.

[image: screenshot]